# Add new [] values to ExpandoObject

Tags: c#, arrays, expandoobject

I want to add all values from `myArr` to `myObj`.

```cs
int[,] myArr = {
    {1, 2},
    {3, 4}
};

dynamic myObj = new ExpandoObject();

foreach(var myInt in myArr)
{
    myObj.Ints = new[]
    {
        new
        {
            value = myInt,
            value_plus_1 = myInt + 1
        }
    };
}
```

At the end of the foreach loop, I would like to have an object like this:

```
Ints: [
  {
    value: 1,
    value_plus_1: 2
  },
  {
    value: 2,
    value_plus_1: 3
  },
  {
    value: 3,
    value_plus_1: 4
  },
  {
    value: 4,
    value_plus_1: 5
  }
]
```

But every iteration I overwrite the value from the previous iteration, so at the end, I have something like this:

```
Ints: [
{
  {
    value: 4,
    value_plus_1: 5
  }
]
```

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every iteration of the loop, `myObj.Ints` is re-set with a new array value.

Instead, you have to add each object to the array via index.

```cs
dynamic myObj = new ExpandoObject();
myObj.Ints = new dynamic[myArr.Length];
        
int index = 0;
foreach(var myInt in myArr)
{
    myObj.Ints[index] = 
        new
        {
            value = myInt,
            value_plus_1 = myInt + 1
        };
                       
    index++;
}
```

[Sample program](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EazsOW)

---

Another way to do is with adding the object into `List` via `System.Linq`. Then assign the list to `myObj.Ints`.

```cs
using System.Linq;

dynamic myObj = new ExpandoObject();
var list = new List<dynamic>();
        
foreach(var myInt in myArr)
{
    list.Add( 
        new
        {
            value = myInt,
            value_plus_1 = myInt + 1
        }
    );
}
        
myObj.Ints = list;
```

[Sample program 2](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KQCwdK)

Comment: Both solutions work perfect, thanks :)